# Printing all palindrome numbers in a given range

Tags: c++, printing, palindrome

I'm trying to write a program that would print all palindrome in range [a, b]. I've written this so far, but nothing is printed after I input the values for a, b. What is missing?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int t = 0, rmd, z, a, b;

int reverse() {
    while (z != 0) {
        rmd = z% 10;
        t = t * 10 + rmd;
        z/= 10;
        }

    return t;
}

int palin() {
    if (a == reverse()) {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
        return 0;

}

int main() {

    cout << "a: "; cin >> a;
    cout << "b: "; cin >> b;

    while (a <= b) {
        z = a;
        if (palin()) 
            cout << a << endl;
        a++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is not a script  it is a program

Comment: you're not reinitialising `t` before each call to `reverse()`

Comment: If you loop `while (a <= b)`, when do you expect `b < a` to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of variables is what is confusing you. The actual issue is not setting t to zero every time you call reverse, but you should think about how you use variable scoping and what functions actually do. Right now you have 2 procedures, that perform actions on global data. Instead try to formulate the problem using functions that accept arguments, and return a result.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int reverse(int z) {
    int t = 0;

    int rmd;
    while (z != 0) {
        rmd = z % 10;
        t = t * 10 + rmd;
        z/= 10;
    }

    return t;
}

int palin(int z) {
    return z == reverse(z);
}

int main() {
    int a, b;

    cout << "a: "; cin >> a;
    cout << "b: "; cin >> b;

    while (a <= b) {
        if (palin(a)) {
            cout << a << endl;
        }
        a++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variable `t` is *not* local to your `reverse()` function. Its value survives to the following invocation, so the result of reverse becomes junk unrelated to the actual call.

You need to make `t` local to `reverse()` in order to fix this problem.

In general, it is a good idea to develop a habit of declaring your variables in the innermost scope to which they could belong without breaking your code. In this case, this would be the scope of `reverse()` function for `t`, and the scope of `main` for the remaining variables; `palin` should take `a` as its parameter.